# Optimal string replacing in files for AIX

Tags: string, replace, awk, sed, find

I need to remove about 40 emails from several files in a distribution list.
One Address might appear in different files and need to be removed from all of them.
I am working in a directory with several .sh files which also have several lines.

I have done something like this in a couple of test files:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -li  ADDRESS_TO_FIND {} 2>/dev/null \; | xargs sed -i 's/ADDRESS_TO_REMOVE/ /g' *
```

It works fine but once I try it in the real files, it takes a long time and just sits there. I need to run this in different servers, this is the main cause I want to optimize this.

I have tried to run something like this:

```
find . -type f -name '*sh' 2>/dev/null | xargs grep ADDRESS_TO_FIND
```

but that will return:

```
./FileContainingAddress.sh:ADDRESS_TO_FIND
```

How do I add something like this:

```
awk '{print substr($0,1,10)}'
```

But to return me everything before the "`:`"?

I can do the rest from there, but haven't found how to trim that part

Comment: Found a solution using
awk -F: '{print $1}'
The final command would be:
find . -type f -name '*1' 2>/dev/null | xargs grep ADDRESS | awk -F: '{print $1}' | xargs sed -i 's/ADDRESS//g' *

Comment: Yes, `awk -F: '{print $1}'` will print the part before the colon but you can avoid it completely with the `-l` switch to grep. I think that you were on the right lines with your original attempt. The `*` at the end of the command should be removed, as I have mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `-exec` as a predicate in `find`, as long as you don't use the multiple file `+` version, which means that you can provide several `-exec` clauses each of which will be dependent on the success of the previous one. This style will avoid the construction of lists of filenames, which makes it much more robust in the face of files with odd characters in their names.

For example:

```
find . -type f -name '*sh' \
     -exec grep -qi ADDRESS_TO_FIND {} \; \
     -exec sed -i 's/ADDRESS_TO_FIND/ /g' {} \;
```

You probably want to provide the address as a parameter rather than having to type it twice, unless you really meant for the two instance to be different (`ADDRESS_TO_FIND` vs. `ADDRESS_TO_REMOVE`):

```
clean() {
  find . -type f -name '*sh' \
       -exec grep -qi "$1" {} \; \
       -exec sed -i "s/$1/ /g" {} \;
}
```

(Watch out for `/` in the argument to `clean`. I'll leave making the `sed` more robust as an exercise.)

Comment: +1 I didn't realise that you could chain `-exec` commands like that, very neat. Although I guess that you can also use `find -print0` and `xargs -0` to deal with problematic file names.

Comment: @TomFenech: `find -print0` and `xargs -0` are not Posix. Anyway, assuming you have Gnu `find` and `xargs`, you can do the initial lookup by filename but you still have to output the filenames from `grep`. Apropos, Posix says with respect to `find` that `-print0` "was considered here, but not adopted. Using a null terminator meant that any utility that was going to process find's -print0 output had to add a new option to parse the null terminators it would now be reading." Indeed. The `-exec .... {} +` form is what was adopted instead.

Comment: @TomFenech: `sed -i` is also non-Posix, so I don't know how it works on AIX. If it works like the Gnu version, then you could use `{} +` for the `-exec sed` clause in my answer, which would be a bit more efficient since it would only fire up a single `sed`.

Comment: sed -i will not work on standard AIX. You need to redirect to a temporary file than a cp or mv. Sometime a double redirection of the same file as input and output work but result is often unpredictible or empty.

Comment: @NeronLeVelu: Redirecting the same file as input and output cannot work, since the shell will truncate the output file before starting the `sed` utility. It doesn't surprise me that AIX `sed` doesn't have the `-i` option but it's in the OP, which suggests that the questioner has a version of `sed` which does support `-i`. It's not impossible to install Gnu sed on AIX.

Answer (score 0):

After looking back at your question, I noticed something that's potentially quite important:

```
find -type f -exec grep -li ADDRESS {} \; | xargs sed -i 's/ADDRESS/ /g' *
# here! -----------------------------------------------------------------^
```

The asterisk is being expanded, so the sed line is operating on *every file in the directory*.

Assuming that this wasn't a typo in your question, I believe that this is the source of your poor performance. You should remove it!